# Cookie in header javascript error "Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie""

Tags: javascript, http

I have check all the post about setting the cookie via Header, and I always see that the people recommend put this:

> withCredentials: true

I'm trying to do it and got the same error.

```
 $scope.myAppsLoginResponse = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 3);
        var dataC = JSON.parse($scope.myAppsLoginResponse);
        $cookies.cookie = 'Somethin here as cookie';

        var userId = dataC.user_id;
        var thePath = '/thePath';
        var theURL = 'https://theUrl';

        var cookieRes = $cookies.cookie;
        document.cookieMyApp = cookieRes;

        var headers2 = {};
            headers2 ['Accept-Language'] = 'es-ES';
            headers2 ['Cookie'] = document.cookieMyApp;
            headers2 ['Authorization'] = 'Basic Z2743ASasdh23Q=';

        var param = {}
            param ['userId'] = userId;

        var req2 = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: theURL + thePath ,
            headers: headers2,
            params: param,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
             }
        }
```

Response:

> Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

JavaScript cannot set cookie headers explicitly.

You can use [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) to set a cookie for the *current* origin.

You can use `withCredentials: true` so that previously set cookies will be sent with a cross-origin Ajax request.

There is no way to change the cookies for a different origin from the current origin although you could set `location.href` to cause the browser to navigate to a URL on the other origin that will send a `set-cookie` header and redirect back to your page.

---

Since you are making a same origin request all you need to do is set `document.cookie` before you make the request.

Answer (score 0):

When you request server side and you need to set cookie.

```
            var setCookie = xhr.getResponseHeader('set-cookie');
```

if the server your requested is on http this error will apear. on Chrom maybe others too. so you juste to request an https server. next when u found an unsafe error on  navigator remind that is according to http. replace it by https