# Next.js with Axios refusing to set Cookie in header, despite then doing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, next.js

I'm working with Next.js, and am getting the following output in my console, which to me suggests that it does set the cookie despite refusing to do so twice. Any idea why it is doing this?[image]

```
import styles from "../styles/Layout.module.css";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
const Layout = ({ children, cookies }: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(cookies["connect.sid"]);
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/status", { withCredentials: true, headers: { Cookie: `connect.sid=${cookies["connect.sid"]}` } })
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setUser(user);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar user={user} loading={isLoading}></Sidebar>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

However, I am also having an issue where despite the user successfully logging to the console in my Sidebar component, it's just passing undefined as the prop - but I am unsure if this is related.

Comment: @yousoumar I realise that I forgot too attach the error - my apologies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookie in header javascript error "Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256737/cookie-in-header-javascript-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-cookie)

Comment: @yousoumar No, as that doesn't explain why it then does successfully execute the request.

Comment: The error you are seeing  is because you cannot set a cookie trough a request in the browser, where your code is being executed, and that's what the answer there is saying.

Comment: Cookies are sent automatically to the server if that's what you are trying to do. Try removing that `headers`.